# Adjust counter from active sheet to specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ShowUserForm1()

''Check where the last row is on column B
'' The counter removes one because the first cell is "Topic"
counter = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

While (Range("D" & counter).Value) = ""
 counter = counter - 1
Wend


'' Loop through all the objects in the userform
'' In this example, it's important that the label and textbox will be names Label# / TextBox# because it removes 5 or 7 strings to extract the object number
'' Check the number of the object, and if it's higher than the counter, hides it

For Each formObject In UserForm1.Controls

    If TypeName(formObject) = "Label" Then
        If Left(formObject.Caption, 5) = "Label" Then
        objectNumber = Right(formObject.Name, Len(formObject.Name) - 5)
    
        'Change the label caption according to the cell value
        formObject.Caption = Cells(CInt(objectNumber) + 1, 4).Value
    
        If CInt(objectNumber) > counter Then formObject.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
    
    If TypeName(formObject) = "TextBox" Then
    objectNumber = Right(formObject.Name, Len(formObject.Name) - 7)
    
    If objectNumber > 12 Then objectNumber = objectNumber - 12
        
    If CInt(objectNumber) > counter - 1 Then formObject.Visible = False
    End If
    
Next


If counter < 5 Then
'' Change the userform height, you can play with the numbers
UserForm1.Height = 70 + 40 * counter
' Move the button up higher
UserForm1.CommandButton1.Top = 40 + 43 * counter - 60

ElseIf counter < 13 Then
'' Change the userform height, you can play with the numbers
UserForm1.Height = 70 + 35 * counter
' Move the button up higher
UserForm1.CommandButton1.Top = 40 + 35 * counter - 60

ElseIf counter > 13 Then
'' Change the userform height, you can play with the numbers
UserForm1.Height = 70 + 50 * counter
' Move the button up higher
UserForm1.CommandButton1.Top = 40 + 53 * counter - 60

End If

UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

My counter starts and only counts with active sheet, is there a way I can convert this to count the same data, but just on a different worksheet?

Active sheet is sheet2, but to have the counter count on sheet1 (inactive)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Adding full code

Comment: `counter = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row`?

Comment: Not yet :/ , Sheet 1 is hidden if that has any effect

Comment: `counter = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row`, the rows number of all sheets  is the same,  so sheet1.rows.count is same with rows.count.

Comment: @Dy.Lee - "the rows number of all sheets is the same" - technically no, that will fail if a chart sheet is active.

Comment: @BigBen No hope?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure `Sheet1` is the one you want to refer to? Is the column number `4` correct?

Comment: @BigBen Here's the full code, posting so I dont miss anything :/ Sheet1 called "User Dashboard" is definetely the refer sheet and column 4 is accurate, when I open this on sheet1, it works as intended, and switching sheets makes it only count the D column (column 4) of active sheet

Comment: `While (Range("D" & counter).Value)` - missing a reference to sheet1. Though I have no clue why you're doing that, you already got the last row. `Cells(CInt(objectNumber) + 1, 4).Value` also is referring to the active sheet.

Comment: May I ask your suggestion? I thought because counter was already set, the word reference would equal the value of counter, should I put it as range("D" & counter = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: No, you should get rid of that `While...Wend` entirely. I have no clue what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: It's a macro that pushes userform to changes labels to cell value

Comment: It makes no sense to me why you'd try to modify `counter` with that loop.

Comment: Can I move this to chat with you? The site is asking me to avoid extended discussions haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222186/discussion-between-bigben-and-kevin-billings).

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim counter As Long
    
    Set Ws = Sheet1
    
    With Ws
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        counter = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden '<~~ you can't set visibility on the sheet
        '.Visible = xlSheetHidden '<~~ you can set visibility on the sheet
    End With
    Stop
End Sub
```